# using VIX to approximate BS IV for short term S&P ATM calls

Tags: black-scholes, vix

what kind of adjustments are needed to VIX series so that it could be used to approximate BS IV in calculating near-term (EDIT: weeklys) SPY at-the-money call premiums/deltas?

thanks a lot.

Comment: VIX should be a good estimate of ATM vol for 30 day SPY options

Comment: I was thinking weeklys. Last week, SPY 1 week 0.5% OTM calls had an IV of ~14% while VIX was several points higher. It could also be the other way, perhaps. So I feel using VIX as is is error prone

Comment: I'm surprised no one publishes an SP500 volatility surface regularly. Google around for this. I found a few hits almost immediately.